# Unix - how to apply a field separating delimiter that accounts for exceptions

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a CSV file that I am trying to separate by field within a Unix environment. The CSV file is separated by commas, and some fields have values that use multiple commas like so:

> NAME,DATE,SIZE,COLORS,TICKET
>
> James, 11/20/10, XL, "YELLOW, BLUE, RED", true
>
> Amy, 11/25/10, S, "BLUE, GREEN", false
>
> Jack, 12/01/10, M, GREEN, true

Running a cut command with a comma delimiter doesn't properly split the fields because it counts the commas used inside some of the COLORS values. The same issue happens when using the awk command and applying -F or -FS:

```
awk  '{print $4,$5}' FS="," file.csv
awk -F"," '{print $4,$5}' file.csv
cut -d ',' -f4,5 file.csv
```

All of the code used above incorrectly split the fields and output something like this:

> COLORS TICKET
>
> "YELLOW BLUE
>
> "BLUE GREEN
>
> GREEN true

Is there a way to apply a delimiter that splits the fields of the CSV properly and that would account for exception values where it's wrapped by double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `gawk` you can try FPAT variable to define fields instead of specifying field delimiter.  However, in your particular case it might be easier just to filter out the first 3 fields

```
$ awk '{sub(/([^,]+,){3} ?/,"")}1' file

COLORS,TICKET
"YELLOW, BLUE, RED", true
"BLUE, GREEN", false
GREEN, true
```

or similarly with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([^,]+,){3} ?//'
```

Comment: Thank you! For using awk or sed, is there a way to filter out selected fields? Such as filtering out the 1st, 2nd, and 4th but keeping the 3rd and 5th.

Comment: `awk '{print $3,$NF}' file` should do in this case as well.